# Calling functions in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function

I'm trying to get a function to call in html and I cant seem to figure it out. I'm using angularJS and I've tried using both `onClick = "function();"` and `ng-click = "function();"`
Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<button ng-hide="tableAttrs.hide" onclick="moveToLoc()">Search</button>
```

JS:

```
function moveToLoc() {
    siteId = document.getElementById('input').value;
    alert(siteId);
    map.panTo(siteId);
    tableAttrs.hide = !tableAttrs.hide;
  }
```

In the console I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: moveToLoc is not defined` 
**What am I doing wrong???**

Comment: What is happening that is wrong? What does the console show when you click the button?

Comment: do you really have an element with `id="input"`?

Comment: yeah I was using it to test something im about to change it. @bansi

Comment: it says moveToLoc(); is not defined... @Renan

Comment: @IanPennebaker may be a case where the script is not being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following the angularJS documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

You can add ngClick attribute to your button object as the following example:

```
<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment
</button>
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

if your `moveToLoc()` is in a controller you need to bind it to the `$scope` - otherwise your view doesn't know about it.

so in your controller use:

```
$scope.moveToLoc = function() {
    //code
  }
```

and in your view use:

```
<button ng-hide="tableAttrs.hide" ng-click="moveToLoc()">Search</button>
```

Besides this,if `moveToLoc()` is in a controller, you also are mixing DOM and business logic.Calling things like `siteId = document.getElementById('input').value` is not something that should be in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it is still saying that it is undefined? Any other ideas? @darren

Comment: Then you clearly have a whole bunch of other issues. Would need to see your Q updated with your angular controller for starters.

Comment: To be honest i'm not sure what my "Q updated with my angular controller" is. But here is a plunk of the entire application if you want to take a lookzie: http://plnkr.co/edit/OZZRgiEcrLzreW3lrc5v?p=preview @darren